# Classifying the singularities of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, singularity

I'm trying to classify the singular points of the following function but I'm having some troubles.

$$f(z) = \frac{z(z-1)^{1/3}\sin(1/z)}{(z^2+1)^3\sin(z)}$$

This is what I have so far:

1. $z=i, z=-i$ are poles of order 3 because of the third power in the denominator.
2. Because of the $\sin(z)$ we have simples poles for $z=n\pi, n \in Z$
3. I suspect that $0$ is also a singularity because of the $\sin(1/z)$ but I'm not sure.

What do you think ?

Comment: What does $(z-1)^{1/3}$ mean?

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{z-1} $ maybe that is more understandable, my apologies !

Comment: And what does *that* mean?

Comment: I don't see how it would help me here, since $(z^2+1)=(z-i)(z+i)$. Maybe I'm missing out something.

Comment: What is it that you don't see how it would help you?

Comment: I don't see how the $(z-a)^{1/3}$ is helpful here. Sometimes you can find a removable singularity using terms in the nominator but here no idea how or if it is the case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141764/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-bsaoptima).

Answer (score 0):

The first two point are correct.

1. $z=i, z=-i$ are poles of order 3 because of the third power in the denominator.
2. Because of the $\sin(z)$ we have simples poles for $z=n\pi, n \in Z$

Now recalling $sin(\frac{1}{z})= Imm(e^{\frac{1}{z}})$ by developing in series $sin(1/z)=\sum_{k, dispari}(i)^{k-1}(\frac{1}{z})^k(\frac{1}{k!})$ Intuitevely $sin(1/z)=\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{6z^3}+...$. Which is by definition an
[essenzial singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity).

Comment: I think point 2 is wrong: the case $n=0$ is special, you can't just pull out the $\sin z$ alone, you've go to worry about the other parts of the formula.

Comment: I just copied what he wrote in the first two part, if you consider just $1/sin(z)$ then he is right. I think the aim of the exercise is just finding different type of singularities. Otherwise you are right.